# how to access refs in parent when child component is exported with withStyles?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

for eg.

Child.js

```
//assume there is s as styles object and used in this component
class Child extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
    <h1 ref={(ref)=>{this.ref = ref}}>Hello</h1>
  );
 }
}

export default withStyles(s)(Child);
```

Parent.js

```
class Parent extends Component {
 onClick() {
    console.log(this.child) // here access the ref
    console.log(this.child.ref) // undefined
 }
 render() {  
  return (
    <div>
      <Child ref={child => this.child = child} />
      <button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```

due to with styles the whole this.child ref in the parent component is changed. Please help me out with a workaround for this, dropping the withStyles is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your child component a prop with method onRef like follows:

```
class Child extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onRef(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1 ref={(ref) => { this.ref = ref }}>Hello</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Then in your parent method you can access Child ref using callback as follows:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  onClick() {
    console.log(this.childHoc) // here access the withStyle ref
    console.log(this.actualChild) // here access the actual Child Component ref
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child ref={childHoc => this.childHoc = childHoc} onRef={actualChild => this.actualChild = actualChild} />
        <button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of an innerRef prop and use it to get the ref of the child like

```
class Child extends Component {
 componentDidMount() {
    this.props.innerRef(this);
 }
 render() {
  return (
    <h1 ref={(ref)=>{this.ref = ref}}>Hello</h1>
  );
 }
}

export default withStyles(s)(Child);
```

and in parent

```
class Parent extends Component {
 onClick() {
    console.log(this.child) // here access the ref
    console.log(this.child.ref) // undefined
 }
 render() {  
  return (
    <div>
      <Child innerRef={child => this.child = child} />
      <button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Life Saver (y). Can you point to a link that explains innerRef in detail or please explain how it works.

Comment: The above solution shows error "this.props.innerRef is not a function", but works on removing the componentDidUpdate part ??

Comment: Thanks a ton! Two days of head hitting the wall and you saved me with your answer.

Comment: What would be the notation if you have the child component in a loop? Multiple instances of same child component like repeating box or chart? How would you ref it with this innerRef approach?

Comment: @Vlado, in such a case, you would make this.child to be an object with key being the id of the element rendered in loop. `<Child innerRef={child => this.child[id] = child} />`

Comment: Thanks, I managed to achieve it: https://jsfiddle.net/pum1cq5r/4/